# Missing tags from comments in media received from Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

When I pull media using either the user or tag endpoint, the received media not always contains all tags for a post. This seems (we are still in sandbox mode) to be the case when the tags are contained in comments BUT not always.

E.g: Requesting tag "arkiromantix" (`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/arkiromantix?access_token=[access_token]`).

Returned data contains among others post with id 1192868766714482828_38257867 which lists the requested tag under tags and post with id 1218885626018570787_210152727 which does not.

But with both posts the tag in question was added in a comment not in the caption.

My questions would be:

1. Is there a way to assure getting all tags (from caption and authors comments) when pulling media from the Instagram API? (For now I am requesting the comments for each media, which increases the amount of requests the app uses considerably). And if not:
2. Is there a rule by which Instagram decides when they return all tags (from caption and comments) and when not? (So i can at least reduce the amount of requests)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tags in comments count as tags on the gram itself **if and only if the comment was written by the user that posted the image**. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496881/tags-tag-name-media-recent-endpoint-returns-media-in-unexpected-order) deals with a related issue (i.e. retrieving recent grams with a given hashtag doesn't actually sort by post date of the gram if the hashtag is in a comment made by the gram's poster, but instead by post date of that comment, in that case). See in particular [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496881/tags-tag-name-media-recent-endpoint-returns-media-in-unexpected-order?lq=1#comment60835787_36496881).

I can confirm this (undocumented!) sorting quirk from personal experience from the past two days ... this sort of thing really makes work interesting.