# /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent endpoint returns media in unexpected order

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Up until recently the /tags/{*tag-name*}/media/recent [endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) returned the media ordered by 'create_time' in descending order (from newer to older posts).

But lately sometimes there are posts returned within a sequence that don't follow this logic, see the following example:

A) Getting the latest 66 posts with tag "dinobots" (a total of two requests sent to the endpoint). I'm just outputting:

1. data.media.create_time
2. data.media.create_time formatted as date
3. data.media.id

(Mind you, I run this test on the 5th of April and am based in Spain - UTC/GMT +2)

```
[2016-04-05T14:25:39.356Z] instagram.getTagMedia | tag(dinobots) num(66)
[2016-04-05T14:25:39.357Z] __send:  { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/dinobots/media/recent',
  qs: 
   { access_token: '****',
     count: 66 } }
* BATCH [1] i: time|date|id
  0: 1459831400|Tue Apr 05 2016 06:43:20 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1221476781088786637_2199878025
  1: 1459806250|Mon Apr 04 2016 23:44:10 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1221265804006866125_145907638
  2: 1459806030|Mon Apr 04 2016 23:40:30 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1221263961941362171_27800016
  3: 1459803502|Mon Apr 04 2016 22:58:22 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1221242752977508128_2270469004
  4: 1459797781|Mon Apr 04 2016 21:23:01 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1221194761482324932_1983283633
  5: 1459795141|Mon Apr 04 2016 20:39:01 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1221172616948852241_1481957792
  6: 1459791804|Mon Apr 04 2016 19:43:24 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1221144618979830053_16912825
  7: 1459759772|Mon Apr 04 2016 10:49:32 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220875921490574745_2204054478
  8: 1459759199|Mon Apr 04 2016 10:39:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220871112347505480_2138805147
  9: 1459747823|Mon Apr 04 2016 07:30:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220775685988451266_47914511
 10: 1459739013|Mon Apr 04 2016 05:03:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220701782779270200_2270469004
 11: 1459729994|Mon Apr 04 2016 02:33:14 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220626120227496971_2135828656
 12: 1459723676|Mon Apr 04 2016 00:47:56 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220573124211688587_1238240432
 13: 1459719310|Sun Apr 03 2016 23:35:10 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220536498492875969_41021096
 14: 1459717291|Sun Apr 03 2016 23:01:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220519563697845780_33587044
 15: 1459715451|Sun Apr 03 2016 22:30:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220504122932520166_144254792
 16: 1459712975|Sun Apr 03 2016 21:49:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220483356344851535_2878468462
 17: 1459711405|Sun Apr 03 2016 21:23:25 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220470187338016380_1906413880
 18: 1459708173|Sun Apr 03 2016 20:29:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220443073341475244_1542131713
 19: 1459613301|Sat Apr 02 2016 18:08:21 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219647231831493625_1542131713
 20: 1459698643|Sun Apr 03 2016 17:50:43 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220363133557136321_1188882549
 21: 1459693153|Sun Apr 03 2016 16:19:13 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220317075470193760_2270469004
 22: 1459058162|Sun Mar 27 2016 07:56:02 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1214990384828005207_1263918085
 23: 1459653372|Sun Apr 03 2016 05:16:12 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219983365973449998_1419533814
 24: 1459651472|Sun Apr 03 2016 04:44:32 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219967435570941123_1981029098
 25: 1459650573|Sun Apr 03 2016 04:29:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219959889556672450_1981029098
 26: 1459642678|Sun Apr 03 2016 02:17:58 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219893664421601343_1163231623
 27: 1459627372|Sat Apr 02 2016 22:02:52 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219765262644426706_2232444620
 28: 1459627347|Sat Apr 02 2016 22:02:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219765056695711694_2232444620
 29: 1459627254|Sat Apr 02 2016 22:00:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219764274558678968_2232444620
 30: 1459596410|Sat Apr 02 2016 13:26:50 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219505541454432726_2993160193
 31: 1459571618|Sat Apr 02 2016 06:33:38 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219297567633586097_286114876
 32: 1459562662|Sat Apr 02 2016 04:04:22 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219222438194182711_637109093
[2016-04-05T14:25:40.408Z] __send:  { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/dinobots/media/recent',
  qs: 
   { access_token: '****',
     count: 33,
     max_tag_id: 'AQAC-_e5oN2cg42GK8tRVWHTR2l_bmPGUbqP63a__dZQJlod2KjspnJvRy98w3uzwz4o_wV8RqG2gCtMUXyV9-Gk1HZgVXWIoy1WLbyG0Q-iqzZ14zOsSqb7pF6zhFHIHRZcpxXxZLgrYjB_gLf9rzqonrQiKYfUmAO8u4inLODyzA' } }
* BATCH [2] i: time|date|id
  0: 1459560102|Sat Apr 02 2016 03:21:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219200967918851404_1703551892
  1: 1459547514|Fri Apr 01 2016 23:51:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219095371524197270_195840369
  2: 1459544999|Fri Apr 01 2016 23:09:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219074275068545453_2951569545
  3: 1459051997|Sun Mar 27 2016 06:13:17 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1214938669235826889_213123067
  4: 1459052492|Sun Mar 27 2016 06:21:32 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1214942819474469175_213123067
  5: 1459052556|Sun Mar 27 2016 06:22:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1214943359633715533_213123067
  6: 1459052611|Sun Mar 27 2016 06:23:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1214943818138251608_213123067
  7: 1459535486|Fri Apr 01 2016 20:31:26 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218994468785293515_3091006857
  8: 1459533643|Fri Apr 01 2016 20:00:43 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218979011884719530_14650742
  9: 1459504269|Fri Apr 01 2016 11:51:09 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218732606116981179_2122189729
 10: 1459498332|Fri Apr 01 2016 10:12:12 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218682803311688712_5849430
 11: 1459493347|Fri Apr 01 2016 08:49:07 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218640983500340634_5849430
 12: 1459491118|Fri Apr 01 2016 08:11:58 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218622286942690705_247086526
 13: 1459491082|Fri Apr 01 2016 08:11:22 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218621983862283662_247086526
 14: 1459490181|Fri Apr 01 2016 07:56:21 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218614421375354133_9584032
 15: 1459474952|Fri Apr 01 2016 03:42:32 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218486678602978917_1322952884
 16: 1459461694|Fri Apr 01 2016 00:01:34 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218375456665029004_31081201
 17: 1459458932|Thu Mar 31 2016 23:15:32 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218352289019267493_2951569545
 18: 1459458729|Thu Mar 31 2016 23:12:09 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218350586937149806_2951569545
 19: 1459458490|Thu Mar 31 2016 23:08:10 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218348580767992124_2951569545
 20: 1459444761|Thu Mar 31 2016 19:19:21 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218233415058429131_2864911124
 21: 1459443673|Thu Mar 31 2016 19:01:13 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218224284066391892_250785520
 22: 1459429800|Thu Mar 31 2016 15:10:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218107910669114954_10570422
 23: 1459428169|Thu Mar 31 2016 14:42:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218094231797401013_346448872
 24: 1459396719|Thu Mar 31 2016 05:58:39 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1217830412005828696_2372444505
 25: 1459387494|Thu Mar 31 2016 03:24:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1217753025130548975_523181042
 26: 1459387375|Thu Mar 31 2016 03:22:55 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1217752027677564793_1419533814
 27: 1459386578|Thu Mar 31 2016 03:09:38 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1217745340402257415_523181042
 28: 1459377048|Thu Mar 31 2016 00:30:48 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1217665400246998751_239425100
 29: 1459353118|Wed Mar 30 2016 17:51:58 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1217464653344858895_2210453511
 30: 1459349295|Wed Mar 30 2016 16:48:15 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1217432584813406743_2122189729
 31: 1459308310|Wed Mar 30 2016 05:25:10 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1217088778175783414_1608359615
 32: 1459230785|Tue Mar 29 2016 07:53:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1216438454380937231_1582180015
[2016-04-05T14:25:41.497Z] DONE
```

We can see the unexpected behaviour in both requests:

**Request 1**

```
 18: 1459708173|Sun Apr 03 2016 20:29:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220443073341475244_1542131713
 19: 1459613301|Sat Apr 02 2016 18:08:21 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219647231831493625_1542131713
 20: 1459698643|Sun Apr 03 2016 17:50:43 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220363133557136321_1188882549
 21: 1459693153|Sun Apr 03 2016 16:19:13 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1220317075470193760_2270469004
 22: 1459058162|Sun Mar 27 2016 07:56:02 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1214990384828005207_1263918085
 23: 1459653372|Sun Apr 03 2016 05:16:12 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219983365973449998_1419533814
```

I would not have expected posts 19 and 22 to appear in this sequence (at least in this position)

**Request 2**

```
  2: 1459544999|Fri Apr 01 2016 23:09:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1219074275068545453_2951569545
  3: 1459051997|Sun Mar 27 2016 06:13:17 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1214938669235826889_213123067
  4: 1459052492|Sun Mar 27 2016 06:21:32 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1214942819474469175_213123067
  5: 1459052556|Sun Mar 27 2016 06:22:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1214943359633715533_213123067
  6: 1459052611|Sun Mar 27 2016 06:23:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1214943818138251608_213123067
  7: 1459535486|Fri Apr 01 2016 20:31:26 GMT+0200 (CEST)|1218994468785293515_3091006857
```

ditto for posts from 3 to 5 (included)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I originally sent this enquiry to Instagram Support but haven't hear from them yet. It doesn't always happen but I've seen this strange behaviour in a few tags already, making the process of filtering by date a bit inconsistent.

Kind regards,

David

Comment: Yeah something is clearly broken with their API. I have also filed a report (two weeks ago) but haven't heard anything yet. There are a couple of threads here on Stackoverflow mentioning this problem

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joel, upon further investigation it looks like new comments which include the seek tag appear earlier in the sequence (are treated as newer) than older pictures that were created with that same tag (the tag is in the caption field), though not sure if this is always the case.

Comment: Here's the main thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354495/instagram-api-tags-tag-name-media-recent-changed-behaviour

Comment: Thanks @xecgr, I haven't got enough reputation yet to post comments on other threads. I've got more insights. It appears that only comments that include the hashtag and that are made by the same user that posted the media count towards the sequence. ie.

1. user1 posted picture A in 2014 with tag "hello"
2. many pics are posted since then till now
3. user1 add a new comment to picture A including tag "hello"
4. get recent media from IG, picture A would appear the first in the sequence

Comment: What I don't know yet is what would happen if user1 posts picture B without any hashtag and later on edits the same picture and adds hashtag "hello"

Comment: Any news on this? I am having the same issue (also based in Spain, not that I think it is relevant)

Comment: Nope, never got any reply back from Instagram. They tend to make changes without communicating them, in fact I don't think they even have a channel to make such announcements. Last error I've been experiencing lately is that for certain hashtags some replies contain a malformed json payload (ie. as if the json document had been cut)